# How to properly permanently seal a duct opening?

Tags: ducts, exhaust-vent

I recently hired a handyman to install an over the range hood. To install it, he cut a hole in the bottom of the upper cabinets and routed the duct through the back of the cabinet's, into a vertical exhaust duct.

There was an existing hole into the duct that I decided wasn't worth it to try and re-use ([see details here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/210611)) and so it needed to be closed up. I expected the handyman to seal the vent using some sort of metal covering, but instead he sprayed expanding foam into it, and then it looks like he attempted to cover it with drywall compound after a few hours (or minutes - I wasn't there when he completed the job). It didn't seem like a great idea to me when I saw it, and now a few days later the expanding foam has expanded even further, making a bumpy mess on the wall.

**First, I'm concerned that this is above my stove.** It's not a gas stove, but expanding foam is highly flammable, isn't it? Is this a safe thing to do?

**Secondly, what would have been the proper way to seal that duct?** Or is filling it with expanding foam fine? I'm thinking of cutting out the entire area of drywall and replacing it, but I still wouldn't know what to do with the hole in the exhaust duct.

Before the hood was installed, and the foam was sprayed :

[image: Before installing the hood and closing the duct]

After the hood was installed, before the drywall compound

[image: after spray foam, before drywall compound]

Comment: if it is in an outside wall of the house, I would pack fiberglass insulation into the unused duct to reduce heat loss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would disconnect it from the vertical stack so it would be easier to seal. Then remove the box from the wall or at least bend it/ push in into the space between the studs. Get some drywall clamps or some furring strips and attach them inside the opening and then screw a piece of drywall cut to fit into the opening. Tape and paint.

A lot of that foam is flammable so if it's on the surface that's not good and should be removed.

Comment: Hmm, I understand the part about the furring to repair the drywall, but what would I disconnect from the vertical stack? How would I seal it? I didn't understand the first couple of sentences.

Comment: That box connects to duct work that routes the fumes to the outside. Just disconnect it at an easy spot so you could hopefully remove the box. Then seal  the opening in the rest of the duct work  with a cap from your home store or make one from Styrofoam  and secure it with duct tape. Did the handyman  connect to the existing duct or add all new?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The handyman connected to existing duct, just higher up the wall (inside the cabinet above). So just to be clear, you're suggesting that I remove the existing drywall, remove the now unused part of the ductwork including the box, add an endcap, and then install new drywall?

Answer (score 0):

Drywall is by nature a fire retardant so that is likely the best choice.
And continue the tile the rest of the way up.
Any type of foam product will melt at temps above 250 degrees and put off deadly fumes when it does so never use foam or plastics near high heat.

Answer (score 0):

Cover that complete section of wall behind the range hood with drywall. and/or 1/4 inch HardiBack if you want to continue the wall tile to under/behind the hood.